# How to wrap an OCaml expression with unit ()?

Tags: ocaml

The following expression `3 ; ()` in utop results in the below response

```
utop # 3 ; ();;
Characters 0-1:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
Characters 0-1:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
- : unit = ()
```

How can we make a non-`unit` expression (like `3`) return `unit` to work with the semicolon operator?

Comment: The warning is an indication that 3 is dead code, the value is never used; maybe the fix is to remove it, or to update a ref, or to call another function that returns unit()

Comment: @coredump What if the expression mutates a data structure?

Comment: Virtually all such expressions in OCaml have unit type (by design).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `ignore` for just this purpose.

```
# ignore 3; ();;
- : unit = ()
#
```

Comment: adding the ````; ()```` is probably not useful anymore

Comment: It's nice to see that the warning from the `;` operator goes away.